# Microservices db design issues

Tags: microservices

I've just started separating my projects out into little microservices. I have a microservice which deals with API authorization (checks if an apiKey provided in an API request is valid) and so for this, I have a separate DB for the API Authorization which has the following tables with the following schema:

APIKey:
ApiKey (VARCHAR, PK)
TenantID (INT, FK)

Tenant:
TenantID (INT, PK)
Name (VARCHAR)

As you can see the APIKey table is linked to the Tenant table.

I have another microservice, this microservice deals with storing errors for tenants and so requires reference to the tenant table, but because the Tenant table is in a separate DB, we can't actually use it.

I thought about creating a Tenant service and having a DB just for Tenants but this would cause data integrity issues on other microservices which require some reference to a Tenant so I'm not sure what I should do.

Can anyone suggest what should be done?

Answer (score 0):

The microservice for tenant errors seems to be a nano service. It sounds like you're actually using it for monitoring. There are more monitoring solutions out there such as Splunk and ELK that can do more generic logging. If you have other microservices, they can also log the errors to them.

If you used a monitoring solution, you wouldn't need a tenant error microservice and you also wouldn't need a tenant microservice as you suggested. If you wanted to continue down the path of having individual services though, you could publish the error events and tenant events to a queue from the API authorization service to the tenant microservice or tenant error service. So you will have replicated data and will need to strategize keeping the data consistent.

Arguably, this leads more complexity due to how you decided to split it into those respective microservices. On the other hand, a shared architecture would solve your problem but at the same time, couples your architecture. The reason microservices exist is to essentially to move away from coupling so I would recommend going back to evaluate whether that decision on defining those bounds for the services and see what you can join together to either eliminate or minimize the complexity.

Comment: If in this case I didn't want to use a 3rd party monitoring tool, what should be done? Are you saying I should replicate the data onto other microservices? So if a tenant exists in one microservice then all other microservices which require a tenant should be told and so the tenant should be copied onto other services too?

Comment: Right replicating via publishing, as indicated in the second sentence of the second paragraph.

Comment: @KTOV, added some more color and alternatives to the replicating data sets but again, ultimately recommend re-evaluating the direction the bounds of the services.